# How to group by in R

Tags: r, group-by

[image: i also want to add the mean for member and casual , which are in member_casual column in a data frame,]

the command i earlier used to group_by is

```
new1 %>% 
  group_by(months_tb) %>% 
  summarise(mean1 =mean(duration))
```

new1 is the table and months_tb is column (and memeber_casual is also a column which consist of member and casual only) how should i find out mean for member and casual as well?

in plus tell me how can i summarise the data as count instead of mean?

Comment: Please share your data using `dput(new1)`? So we can help you better.

Comment: for count per group you could use `n()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use to count :

`new1 %>%  group_by(months_tb) %>% summarise(duration= n())`